# how to store and delete sorted items in a file

Tags: algorithm, external-sorting

I am trying to store elements in a file in a sorted order.
The elements will be in the following format:

```
1 MessageA
2 MessageB
.
.
54 MessageM
68 MessageN
```

Each element will have a number(timestamp) & a message(size is variable).

The elements must be sorted by timestamp.

Operation allowed are insert and delete(Pop).

(Growing file size is not an issue)

and we can delete only from the lower most element(i.e. delete one after another).

Currently I have implemented it as a linked list which is very slow on inserts when the number of elements are large.

what will be the most efficient data structure to store this?

Comment: Look up a Binary Search Tree

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to delete the oldest or the newest element but you should probably look into *stacks* and *queues*.

Stacks are First In Last Out, meaning that the element inserted first will be deleted (popped) last, as it would happen with a real stack, hence the name. Here the popped element would be the newest.

Queues are First In First Out. Here the deleted element (dequeued) is the oldest still present in the queue.